# Spring Boot REST API unsupported media type

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, postman, spring-webclient

I have two API:s , CarRental-API on port 8080 and CarRental-CRUD on port 8081.

CarRental-CRUD uses JpaRepository to access a h2 memory DB.

I want to use CarRental-API to make requests to CarRental-CRUD, using webclient.

In CarRental-CRUD , I can make post requests and add cars to the db using this service:

```
public String addCar(Car car) {
    
    carRepository.save(car);
    
    return loggerService.writeLoggerMsg("CREATED CAR AND ADDED TO DB");
}
```

And then in the controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/crud/v1")
public class AdminCarController {

    @Autowired
    private AdminCarService adminCarService;
    
    @PostMapping(path = "/addcar",  consumes = "application/json")
    public String addCar(@RequestBody Car car) {
        return adminCarService.addCar(car);
    }
}
```

I tried to post a request with webclient in CarRental-API with :

```
@Service
public class AdminCarService {

    @Autowired 
    LoggerService loggerService;
    
    @Autowired
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    public String  addCar(Car car) {

            webClientBuilder
                    .build()
                    .post()
                    .uri("localhost:8081/crud/v1/addcar")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(Car.class);

        return loggerService.writeLoggerMsg("ADDED CAR TO DB");
        }
}
```

However, using the carRental-API , I get this error in postman when I try to post a request :

```
 "status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"trace": "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException: 200 OK from POST localhost:8081/crud/v1/addcar; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=com.backend.carrentalapi.entity.Car\n\tat
```

This is the Car Entity :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_CAR")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long carId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String carName;

    @Column(name = "MODEL")
    private String carModel;

    @Column(name = "DAILY_PRICE")
    private double dailyPrice;


}
```

I can't seem to find where in the code I am producing text/plain. I made sure in postman that I'm posting a raw JSON body request, and the headers say content type : application/json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `WebClient` you are not adding the request body, but instead expecting a `Car` back from the API you are calling (and this API returns a simple `String` instead). The following should work.

```java
@Service
public class AdminCarService {

    @Autowired 
    LoggerService loggerService;
    
    @Autowired
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    public String  addCar(Car car) {

            webClientBuilder
                    .build()
                    .post()
                    .uri("localhost:8081/crud/v1/addcar")
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(car))
                    .retrieve()
                    .toBodilessEntity();

        return loggerService.writeLoggerMsg("ADDED CAR TO DB");
        }
}
```

Using `.toBodilessEntity()` since you don't really do anything with the response.

Comment: Thank you, the post request is now working, but the database doesn't seem to get the value when I add a new car. 

Does this have something to do with the response?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the response. Is your `CarRental-CRUD` service also based on Spring WebFlux?

Comment: No , it is based on the JpaRepository interface

Comment: Did you confirm that the call reached `CarRental-CRUD` Controller using a breakpoint or something else?

Comment: I added a few breakpoints around the controller and sent the request again, but the debugger didn't seem to write out anything. 
I also checked the log in postman, and couldn't find anything other than that the request was ok

Comment: Ok, but then I ask myself if the request is in fact reaching your API. If you add breakpoints in your `CarRental-CRUD` Controller and when you make the request they don't stop there...

Comment: I figured out the issue, I needed to add .block() after .toBodilessEntity(), now it works!

Comment: True, but then your application is not 100% reactive, since you are blocking the thread at that point. Using `.block()` should be avoided at all costs in a fully reactive application and you should deal with `Mono` and `Flux` data types. Instead of `.block()` try `.subscribe()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239035/discussion-between-ruthless-and-joao-dias).